How to add title and note to listing over many pages in latex lstlisting?
I need to center the title on every page of my long listing. In addition, I need to add at the end of the pages the note "continued on next page".
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Programmausdruck}
\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    showstringspaces=false,
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}

\surroundwithmdframed[
hidealllines=true,
firstextra   = {
      \node[anchor=west]
        at (O-|P) {Fortsetzung nächste Seite};
    },
middleextra={
  \node[anchor=west] at (O|-P)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ ~- \textit{Fortsetzung der}};
  \node[anchor=west] at (O-|P)
    {Fortsetzung nächste Seite};},
secondextra={
  \node[anchor=west] at (O|-P)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ ~- \textit{Fortsetzung der}};},
splittopskip=2\baselineskip
]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R, caption=abc, label=lst:c1]

struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;
adsa
dgsgdf
jghj

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


In your example, you forgot load xcolor package with svgnames option. Otherwise you example didn't compiled. I put breaklines option due to some of the lines exceed the margin. Here is the code you need to change:
\surroundwithmdframed[
hidealllines=false,
firstextra={
  \node [overlay] at (O-|P) [red,anchor=east] {continued on next page};},
middleextra={
  \path [overlay] (O|-P) -- node {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ ~- \textit{Fortsetzung}} (P);
  \node [overlay] at (O-|P) [red,anchor=east] {continued on next page};},
secondextra={
  \path [overlay] (O|-P) -- node {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ ~- \textit{Fortsetzung}} (P);},
splittopskip=2\baselineskip
]{lstlisting}

I believe there are two predefined coordinates named (O) for bottom-left corner of the frame, (P) for top-right corner of the frame. Here (O-|P) is the bottom-right conner coordinate. similar, you could access top-left corner using (O|-P). So the code in firstextra is to put a overlayed node (don't count the type box to cause overfull box) at the bottom-right corner of the frame. And the east side of the node (anchor=east) will on bottom-right corner coordinate. And this node only added in the first part of the breaking frames. Similar, the first line of code in middleextra is to put a overlay node in the midway of two coordinates (top-left (O|-P) and top-right(P)) and no anchor specified. Because the default anchor is center. So the center of the node will on the center of two coordinates. Thus your title will be centered in this way.
Here is the full working code:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Programmausdruck}
\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    showstringspaces=false,
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    breaklines
}
%%
\surroundwithmdframed[
hidealllines=false,
firstextra={
  \node [overlay] at (O-|P) [red,anchor=east] {continued on next page};},
middleextra={
  \path [overlay] (O|-P) -- node {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ ~- \textit{Fortsetzung}} (P);
  \node [overlay] at (O-|P) [red,anchor=east] {continued on next page};},
secondextra={
  \path [overlay] (O|-P) -- node {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ ~- \textit{Fortsetzung}} (P);},
splittopskip=2\baselineskip
]{lstlisting}
%%
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption=abc, label=lst:c1]

struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif


struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Edits: Here is the example to make the note:

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Programmausdruck}
\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    showstringspaces=false,
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    breaklines
}
%%
\surroundwithmdframed[
hidealllines=false,
firstextra={
  \node [overlay] at (O-|P) [red,anchor=east] {continued on next page};
  \node [overlay] at (O) [lightgray,anchor=north west,yshift=-0.5\baselineskip,text width=\textwidth,inner sep=0pt,font=\scriptsize,align=justify] {\hrulefill\\a note could be added here. Test effect if the note is longer than one line. Test effect if the note is longer than one line};},
middleextra={
  \path [overlay] (O|-P) -- node {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ ~- \textit{Fortsetzung}} (P);
  \node [overlay] at (O-|P) [red,anchor=east] {continued on next page};
  \node [overlay] at (O) [lightgray,anchor=north west,yshift=-0.5\baselineskip,text width=\textwidth,inner sep=0pt,font=\scriptsize,align=justify] {\hrulefill\\a note could be added here. Test effect if the note is longer than one line. Test effect if the note is longer than one line};},
secondextra={
  \path [overlay] (O|-P) -- node {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\ ~- \textit{Fortsetzung}} (P);},
splittopskip=2\baselineskip
]{lstlisting}
%%
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption=abc, label=lst:c1]

struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif


struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



Thank you very much! That is what I needed. Is it possible to add a note on the left side at the end of every page (under "continued on next page")?; Something like a footnote but without a number.

Yes, you could. By reading the explanation, this can be easily achieved if you understand the syntax. If you still have hard time, I can make the changes when I can access the computer.

@Lara I made the edits.

Thanks for your help!

@Lara please accept the answer if you like.
